# Pandas: Grabbing a specific column after filtering dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

How can I get rid of the ratio line of code?

```
totalCharges_male = df[(df['SeniorCitizen'] == 1) & (df['gender'] == 'Male')]
totalCharges_female = df[(df['SeniorCitizen'] == 1) & (df['gender'] == 'Female')]
ratio = totalCharges_male['TotalCharges'].mean() / totalCharges_female['TotalCharges'].mean() 

print(ratio)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *How can I get rid of the ratio line of code?* - could you explain further?

Comment: I have a feeling we can condense this code... it feels like creating two temporary dataframes isn't the most efficient way to find the ratio between male and female charges of senior citizens.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the loc method.
With it you filter and select columns.

```
meanCharges_male = df.loc[
    (df['SeniorCitizen'] == 1) & (df['gender'] == 'Male'), 
    'TotalCharges'].mean()

meanCharges_female = df.loc[
    (df['SeniorCitizen'] == 1) & (df['gender'] == 'Female'), 
    'TotalCharges'].mean()

ratio = meanCharges_male / meanCharges_female

print(ratio)
```